# System doesn't let me submit my submission for Parameters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation

So this is the content I put into the Parameters section for JavaScript Language > JSON:

```
| Parameter              | Details   |
| ---------------------- | --------- |
| **JSON.parse**        | **Parse a JSON string** |
| `input` (`string`)    | JSON String to be parsed. |
| `reviver` (`function`)| Prescribes a transformation for the input JSON string. |
| **JSON.stringify**    | **Serialize a serializable value** |
| `value` (`string`)    | Value to be serialized according to the JSON specification. |
| `replacer` (`function` or `String[]` or `Number[]`)| Selectively includes certain properties of the `value` object. |
| `space` (`String` or `Number`)| If a `number` is provided, then `space` number of whitespaces will be inserted of readability.<br><br>If a `string` is provided, the string (first 10 characters) will be used as whitespaces. |
```

Somehow the system thinks that it is not a two column table and doesn't let me submit it:

[image]

Is this a bug, or is there something wrong with my formatting?

Comment: Is that table parsing specific to documentation or is that a feature of markdown I've never seen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system rejects Parameter blocks with HTML (or images) in any of the cells. Since your last row contains `<br><br>`, it fails that test. On our development instance, I tested the table with those line break tags removed and the edit passed the checks.

I think the no-HTML rule makes sense, but the error should be more specific in that case. (Also, it should be more specific if someone tries to use an image.)

If the thing you are trying to document is (or looks like) HTML, escape it with a backtick (`). If you need to use a literal pipe character, that can be escaped with a backslash: `\|`.

Comment: So why is it restricted to two columns? I would like to have a column for *Default Value* and *Required?*

Comment: To go along with Craig's comment, it's interesting that this is a place you've chosen to _not_ apply the "UC Irvine design philosophy" of letting your users do what they want, then supporting them.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I happen to agree. I never know exactly what to do with the  Syntax and Parameters section and I would have prefered if they had been relegated to the Remarks section.