# Don't show escaped pipe symbols in Parameters

Tags: bug, documentation, markdown-rendering, documentation-editor

According to the answer from Jon Ercison on [System doesn't let me submit my submission for Parameters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328843/system-doesnt-let-me-submit-my-submission-for-parameters) you have to escape any `|` symbols with a `\` to prevent breaking the required two column table layout.

That is indeed true and it looks good in the preview but once submitted the `\` aren't removed, at least not in [Pulling](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/1308/pulling#t=201607261901542325921).

As you can see its first column had this markup:

```
--[no-]recurse-submodules[=yes|on-demand|no]
```

that doesn't work in preview so you have to add the escapes chars:

```
--[no-]recurse-submodules[=yes\|on-demand\|no]
```

Now it will look good in the preview but once posted the `\` return in the rendered view making the syntax wrong and confusing.

On request of [Braiam](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31915464#31915464) I edited that topic. In my initial attempt I tried to wrap stuff in `<code>` tags because I assumed the markdown parser got upset. That worked for the preview, but didn't let me submit the edit.

I ended up with this markdown:

```
`--[no-]recurse-submodules[=yes`&#124;`on-demand`&#124;`no]`
```

which looked good in preview, was accepted when posted and looks good in the final view.

I expect this to be a bug in the server-side check of allowed markdown. Can this be fixed?

If not, I'll rewrite this question and move my work around to the answer.

Comment: @glor I wondered if it also needed that tag.  I decided it didn't but meh ...

Comment: [Here's a very long url of MD renderer rendering this](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%7C+**Parameters**+%7C+**Details**+%7C%0A%7C+----------+%7C+-------+%7C%0A%7C+%60--quiet%60+%7C+No+text+output+%7C%0A%7C+%60-q%60+%7C+shorthand+for+%60--quiet%60+%7C%0A%7C+%60--verbose%60+%7C+verbose+text+output.+Passed+to+fetch+and+merge%2Frebase+commands+respectively.+%7C%0A%7C+%60-v%60+%7C+shorthand+for+%60--verbose%60+%7C%0A%7C+%60--%5Bno-%5Drecurse-submodules%5B%3Dyes%7Con-demand%7Cno%5D%60+%7C+Fetch+new+commits+for+submodules%3F+(Not+that+this+is+not+a+pull%2Fcheckout)+%7C%0A)

Comment: @rene [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcgw.png) is why I think it's necessary.

Comment: @Glorfindel you can have the same thing using [documentation*]

Comment: @Braiam thanks for the tip - the only disadvantage is that this doesn't work in the mobile app