# Pipe in documentation tables

Tags: bug, documentation

The pipe character cannot be used in tables on Documentaion. The pipe character is used for defining the columns but there seems to be no way of escaping the pipe characters, even not with backticks. I tried:

```
|command|purpose|
|-------|-------|
| `|`   | pipe something|
```

Pipes are not to be underestimated. They

- are used in Windows batch programming
- are used in Linux shell scipting
- are used in logical operations
- sometimes have other special meanings, e.g. in WinDbg

Comment: Can you try with `&#124;`  as I explain [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329696/578411)

Comment: @rene: Yes, that works as long as backticks are not required. I'd like to use it in backticks, which then displays `&#124;` literally.

Comment: Also when you add a backtick right before the htmlentity and a backtick right after it as I show in my question? I have 6 backticks there, and two pipe symbols

Comment: Your work-around is fine, but the backslash is *supposed* to work. Re-reading this, I realize I'm not actually sure *how* backtics should work in tables, so leaving this un-marked until that's resolved.