# Use special characters like | in markdown table dialects in Documentation

Tags: support, bug, documentation, markdown, markdown-rendering

When creating Documentation, how are special characters like `|` treated in SO documentation, especially within tables? This does not get rendered properly, hence there there should be a way to escape these characters. The special character can be in quoted text like in:

```
|   Operators   | 
| --------------| 
| `||`          | 
| `|=`          |
```

or without quotes

```
|   Operators   | 
| --------------| 
| ||            | 
| |=            |
```

Comment: related? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329696/dont-show-escaped-pipe-symbols-in-parameters

Comment: Cry in a corner like @rene...

Comment: @Braiam I do not get what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary workaround you can use HTML `<code>` element instead of backticks:

Example:

```
|   Operators   | 
| --------------| 
| `&&` <code>\|\|</code> `!` | 
| <code>\|=</code> |
```

This renders like that:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this on docs.so? It's interesting... :P

Comment: @Braiam Yes, the screenshot is from Documentation.