# Understanding Downvotes on SO

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason, rules

I asked a question initially (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443424/how-do-you-use-the-character-in-markdown-table-dialects) on SO on use of special characters in markdown tables (general markdown dialects). This has got 2 downvotes as of now. I am trying to understand what is wrong with this question? Have I missed anything here? I would belive questions on markdown, asciidoc, etc. would be on topic. There is a tag for markdown also.

Because this did not get answered for a while I asked [Use special characters like | in markdown table dialects in Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335600/use-special-characters-like-in-markdown-table-dialects-in-documentation) which is more specific to the site (docuemtnation) which did get and answer.

Comment: Usual shopping list SO question - "for unlimited list of languages that use | character explain its usages". You could have narrowed it down to one particular case to be on topic as long as it is not immediately obvious from documentation for given language (neither SO:documentation nor SO:Meta would be on topic on SO itself)... Additionally asking self-answered question is hard - this topic is recently discussed multiple times on Meta - check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d

Comment: The downvotes were before the self answer. Also this is since no one answered this question but I got the answer later on meta I put the answer there as it works in at least 2 of the major markdown implementations. This is not about all languages but it is about table implementation in markdown in general. In mark down there subtle from one implementation to the other though. It is difficult to avoid this subtleties in topics like markdown. E.g. `- A` does not work on SO but works in Github. Any thanks for trying to reasoning. This might be the reasoning downvoters are using.

Comment: Another question arising from this would be should have been split. How do you do A in SO, Github, X, Y, Z. For a topic like markdown I feel this would be duplicates as they are very close and best bundled together.

Comment: People might think it's off-topic since markdown !== programming. I dunno. It's also possible [they just lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> This is not about all languages but it is about table implementation in markdown in general.

And therein lies the problem.

Markdown does not have tables. Certain Markdown *dialects* do, but neither the [original Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) nor the [CommonMark specification](http://spec.commonmark.org/) have tables. As such, your question *as asked* is too broad. You're basically asking about the behavior of literally *dozens* of dialects.

By contrast, your MSO question was quite specific. You asked about the behavior of a *single* dialect of Markdown.

That being said, your question merited close-voting rather than downvoting.