# Question about Markdown on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, markdown

1. Are Markdown questions on-topic on Stack Overflow? Is Markdown considered not programming, hence off-topic? (as per comment by @ivarni). In which case, how do you differentiate Markdown from HTML, CSS, XML, SGML, MS Word / office,  DocBook, AsciiDoc, PanDoc, etc.?
2. As there is not one Markdown
   implementation, how do you deal with the differences?
3. Do you have to reask the question specific to each implementation / flavour / dialect? Do you list them the implementations you are interested in?
4. If you ask multiple implementation / flavour / dialect
   specific question, to be specific rather than group them, what would
   be the criteria to consider them duplicates?
5. What instances can you group multiple subtleties in different flavours into one question?
6. For generic Markdown questions would an answer specific to one
   implementation be acceptable and in what situations (specify it is
   implementation specific, does not specific implementation it is
   valid)?

This is a follow up to: [Understanding Downvotes on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335614/understanding-downvotes-on-so) based on the comments received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define "Markdown Question". Are you asking about how to implement Markdown, perhaps in accord with a specific dialect or standard? Or are you asking about how to write something in Markdown in some way?

The former is on-topic. The latter is... questionable, in most cases. On MSO, questions about SO's Markdown dialect are obviously fine.

There are places where it might be OK to ask about a flavor of Markdown. But that would only be in conjunction with its use in a tool specific to *programming*. Asking how to accomplish something in Doxygen's Markdown, for example. But that's primarily a Doxygen question that happens to touch on its use of Markdown.

Comment: OK. Also HTML, XML are also similar? How is this differentiated from markdown?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena: Similar in what way? I don't see how HTML is in any way similar to Markdown, in their relation to programmers.

Comment: OK. Also there are many question on Word and Office on the site which are like markdown.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena: Did Markdown get embedded scripting functionality that I wasn't aware of? Because I'm fairly sure that Word and Office have embedded scripting functionality. Most such questions are either about that or about how to generate Word-compatible files.

Comment: I feel the stance on markdown on its own is off topic is a bit too though has there is DocBook, AsciiDoc, PanDoc related quesion also.

Comment: `that would only be in conjunction with its use in a tool specific to programming` For instance, GitHub?